Passing pointers when calling C code from C#
I have some C code that I want to call from C#.
There is no need to expose the C's data structures to C#, so C# can just pass about pointers to them.
The basic idea is to get the C# to decide what to do, tell the C to do it, then report the results back -- the C# doesn't have to know much about what the C is doing.
For example in C I have
__declspec(dllexport) long cs_getB() {
    return &B;
}

__declspec(dllexport) int cs_order(long csa) {
    c_struct a = (c_struct *)csa;
    return order(a);
}

int order(c_struct a)
{
  // implementation
  return 0;
}


and in C# I then do
        [DllImport("C:\\whatever.dll", EntryPoint = "cs_getB", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetB();

        [DllImport("C:\\whatever.dll", EntryPoint = "cs_order", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int Order(IntPtr a);



and
IntPtr b = MyDll.GetB()
int bor = MyDll.Order(b);

but the call to MyDll.Order throws

System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Is this approach correct?
How can I get C# to handle (pointers to) data from C and tell the C what to do with it?
Update
Same using long long and intptr_t in C.
Value of type IntPtr returned to C# is 0x00007ffef6de8750.
VisualStudio won't step into the C code.
__declspec(dllexport) intptr_t getB() {
    return &B;
}

where
struct thingy {
  long* m729;
  ...
};
typedef struct thingy* thing;
thing B;


C long is not wide enough to hold a pointer value in 64-bit Windows.

Changed it to long long and same behaviour.

intptr_t from stdint.h or LONG_PTR from Windows would be better. Also, you may need to declare your C functions with __stdcall or WINAPI to match CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall in C# because it will default to __cdecl in C. But the difference between __stdcall and __cdecl is only relevant for 32-bit DLLs because 64-bit uses the same calling convention for both.

@RichardBarraclough I thought Ian's first comment re. long would have solved it. And, with long long I would have expected it to work. Can you print out the "pointer" values (in hex) in both C and C#? Or, put in some breakpoints (under a debugger)? Another thing: As posted, order has an empty body. Can you post the code for // implementation? In cs_getB, where is the declaration of B? Is it global or function scope? I might flesh out the code blocks a bit more.
